# select STR_TO_DATE(('20190919 114121', "%Y-%m-%d %T");

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration

if i'm executing this query

```
select STR_TO_DATE('20190919114121', "%Y-%m-%d %T");
```

its showing ouput as null 
but i need output as 2019-09-19 11:41:21

Answer (score 0):

STR_TO_DATE wants the source format, not the target format, so:

```
select STR_TO_DATE('20190919114121', "%Y%m%d%h%i%s");
```